# Why is glucose not used in many cake recipes?

Tags: baking, sugar

Glucose is used in some recipes to make a cake soft and fluffy (for example, this Strawberry Shortcake recipe video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wc6F_dLJo8o).

What is the reason glucose is not widely used in other cake recipes?

Comment: It's not commonly available in everyday grocery stores in the US, and an awfully large fraction of recipes come from the US. Are you asking for a reason beyond that (i.e. why it hasn't caught on here)?

Comment: Yes. Since Glucose is something that can make cakes more better. Why?

Comment: We call it 'corn syrup' in the US.  What's sold as 'glucose syrup' is typically made from rice, and it'ss a royal pain to work with.  (it's so viscous it's like tar)

Comment: @Joe Ah, I thought corn syrup had more non-glucose sugars than glucose syrup, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glucose is very expensive, unlike caster sugar (sucrose, also commonly called "table sugar") which does the job, and is much easier to work with. Glucose in the modern kitchen is only really used in meringues.

Comment: What about corn syrup?